# If statement "Invalid expression term 'else'

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code gives me an error "Invalid expression term 'else'" when I try to compile it. I cant figure out how to fix it:

```
public double CalcTicketCost(int section, double quantity)
{
    double amount = 0;

    if (int.Parse(lstSectionNumber.SelectedItem.Value) < 150)
    {
        amount = premiumTicket  * quantity;
        return amount;
    }
    {
        else  (int.Parse(lstSectionNumber.SelectedItem.Value) > 150) // This line is where the problem seems to be

        amount = basicTicket * quantity; 
    }
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: It is easier to spot issues like this (and many more) if your code and question are neatly formatted.

Comment: If you work in c#, why not using Visual Studio ? It can be helpful with this kind of mistake.

Comment: @RichardEv Please advice how can I format my code better. aloisdg I do use VS 2012, thats how i spotted my error. L.B Its my first week of learning, I will be reading alot about C# and im already watching tutorials. Thank you everyone for your feedback

Comment: @L.B The OP has said that they are only one week into learning C# so it's not unreasonable that syntax could be causing some confusion. We can be more helpful than simply suggesting that they read documentation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `}` before the `else`, the syntax should be...

```
if (condition)
{
    // condition is true
}
else
{
    // condition is false
}
```

However, you also have a second condition after your `else`, so this should be an `else if`

```
if (condition1)
{
    // condition1 is true
}
else if (condition2)
{
    // condition1 is false, condition2 is true
}
```

Also, your first `return amount` is not required; you can write your method like this:

```
public double CalcTicketCost(int section, double quantity)
{
    double amount = 0;

    if (int.Parse(lstSectionNumber.SelectedItem.Value) < 150)
    {
        amount = premiumTicket * quantity;
    }
    else if (int.Parse(lstSectionNumber.SelectedItem.Value) > 150)
    {
        amount = basicTicket * quantity; 
    }

    return amount;
}
```

You can find [documentation that explains this in more detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx) and lots more at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com).

However, it looks like your code may contain a bug. What should happen if `lstSectionNumber.SelectedItem.Value` **equals** 150? At the moment your method will return `0`. Is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: Thank you so much, you explained everything. I changed my code to            public double CalcTicketCost(int section, double quantity)
   {
                  double amount = 0;

            if 
                (int.Parse(lstSectionNumber.SelectedItem.Value) <= 150)
            {
                amount = amount = (quantity * premiumTicket) + (quantity * serviceCharge);
                return amount;

            }
              else  
           {

               amount = (quantity * basicTicket) + (quantity * serviceCharge);
                     
             }
               return amount;

Comment: Sorry its hard to see the code, but i changed <150 to <=150, since i needed to include 150 to premium ticket price. also i removed condition after else, since i do not need it

Answer (score 2):

```
if
 {}
else{}
```

not

```
 if {}
{ else } }
```